# Why does function.toString() output "[native code]", whereas logging to the console directly displays the function’s source code?

Tags: javascript, function, tostring, console.log

I decided to create a userscript for YouTube live chat.  Here is the code:

```js
const toString = Function.prototype.toString

unsafeWindow.setTimeout = function (fn, t, ...args) {
    unsafeWindow.console.log(fn, fn.toString(), toString.call(fn))
    unsafeWindow.fns = (unsafeWindow.fns ?? []).concat(fn)
    return setTimeout(fn, t, ...args)
}
```

Now look what the output looks like:

[image]

The output for some of the functions is predictable, but look at the other ones!  When you do just `console.log` it, you will see the function body, but if you call `fn.toString()`, you will see `function () { [native code] }`.

But why?  The script is loaded before the page, so the YouTube's scripts couldn't replace the methods.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is because those functions have been passed to `Function.prototype.bind`.

```javascript
> (function () { return 42; }).toString()
'function () { return 42; }'
> (function () { return 42; }).bind(this).toString()
'function () { [native code] }'
```

The `bind` method transforms an arbitrary function object into a so-called *bound function*.  Invoking a bound function has the same effect as invoking the original function, except that the `this` parameter and a certain number of initial positional parameters (which may be zero) will have values fixed at the time of the creation of the bound function.  Functionally, `bind` is mostly equivalent to:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function (boundThis, ...boundArgs) {
    return (...args) => this.call(boundThis, ...boundArgs, ...args);
};
```

Except that the above will, of course, produce a different value after string conversion.  Bound functions are specified to have the same string conversion behaviour as native functions, in accordance with [ECMA-262 11th Ed., §19.2.3.5 ¶2](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-function.prototype.tostring):

> 2. If *func* is a bound function exotic object or a built-in function object, then return an implementation-dependent String source code representation of *func*. The representation must have the syntax of a *NativeFunction*. […]
>
> […]
>
> *NativeFunction*:
>
> **function** *PropertyName* <sub>[~Yield, ~Await]</sub> <sub>opt</sub> ( *FormalParameters* <sub>[~Yield, ~Await]</sub> ) { [native code] }

When printing the function to the console directly (instead of the stringification), the implementation is not bound to any specification: it may present the function in the console any way it wishes.  Chromium’s console, when asked to print a bound function, simply displays the source code of the original unbound function, as a matter of convenience.

---

Proving that this is indeed what happens in YouTube’s case is a bit of a nuisance, since YouTube’s JavaScript is obfuscated, but not exceedingly difficult.  We can open YouTube’s main site, then enter the developer console and install our trap:

```
window.setTimeout = ((oldSetTimeout) => {
    return function (...args) {
        if (/native code/.test(String(args[0])))
            debugger;
        return oldSetTimeout.call(this, ...args);
    };
})(window.setTimeout);
```

We should get a hit at the `debugger` statement very quickly. I hit it in this function:

```javascript
g.mh = function(a, b, c) {
    if ("function" === typeof a)
        c && (a = (0, g.D)(a, c));
    else if (a && "function" == typeof a.handleEvent)
        a = (0, g.D)(a.handleEvent, a);
    else
        throw Error("Invalid listener argument");
    return 2147483647 < Number(b) ? -1 : g.C.setTimeout(a, b || 0)
}
```

The `g.D` function looks particularly interesting: it seems to be invoked with the first argument `a`, which is presumably a function.  It looks like it might invoke `bind` under the hood.  When I ask the console to inspect it, I get this:

```javascript
> String(g.D)
"function(a,b,c){return a.call.apply(a.bind,arguments)}"
```

So while the process is a bit convoluted, we can clearly see that this is indeed what happens.

Comment: Awesome!!!
Thank you very much!
By the way, nice way of monkey patching, I will use that too (I used to create an unnecessary variable before)